# How to calculate bias when true population mean is unknown?

Tags: regression, bias

I'm working on a problem with a simulation that calculated a linear regression coefficient from some randomly generated data, which was performed 100 times. In other words, I've got 100 randomly generated $\hat\beta$ values. I'm being asked to compute the bias of the average of my estimates, i.e. being asked to find $\hat\beta - \beta$. But since I don't know $\beta$, how do I calculate this bias?

Comment: How did you randomly generate data *without* knowing $\beta$?  It would be interesting to learn how you accomplished that.

Comment: @whuber - the code generates a set of random numbers, then randomly assigns some of them to be "NA". The assignment gave me a batch of code and told me to run it and interpret the results. I don't think the intent here is to modify the code so that I can record the values of the numbers prior to the random assignments of NA.

Comment: Please provide the details, because the code must contain all the information you need.  And how do you deal with the NA values in your linear regression?

Comment: @whuber I will pass, since the correct approach here is not to modify the code. It should be enough to know that the data was generated with a random number generation function in R, that NA values were also independently generated and injected into the datasets, and imputation was then used to fill in these NA slots. It's a simulation problem that evaluates the effectiveness of the imputation process.

Comment: I am not suggesting modifying the code.  I am suggesting that you *look* at it.  Only then will you (or anyone else) be able to answer your question.  At the very minimum, if you hope to get useful help you will need to explain what that code is trying to do.

Comment: I have looked at the code and understand completely what it is doing. It is generating data and then being modified. Posting it here for you to see it for yourself won't change that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135480/discussion-between-dan-w-and-whuber).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's look at the `R` code you posted in the chat.

```
X_123 <- rmvnorm(n, mean = rep(0, 3),
sigma = matrix(c(1, 0.6, 0.36, 0.6, 1, 0.6, 0.36, 0.6, 1),
nrow = 3, ncol = 3))
X1 <- X_123[, 1]
X2 <- X_123[, 2]
X3 <- X_123[, 3]
X4 <- rbinom(n, 1, expit(0.5*X1 + 0.5*X2 - 0.5*X3))
X5 <- rbinom(n, 1, expit(0.5*X1 - 0.5*X2 + 0.5*X3 - 0.5*X4))
Y <- 2 + X1 + X2 + X3 + 2*X4 + 2*X5 + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 3)
# Add in some missing data
X1_obs <- rbinom(n, 1, expit(1 + 0.25*X2 + 0.25*X3 + 0.125*X4 + 0.125*X5))
X4_obs <- rbinom(n, 1, expit(1 + 0.25*X1 + 0.25*X2 + 0.25*X3 + 0.125*X5))
X1 <- ifelse(X1_obs == 1, X1, NA)
X4 <- ifelse(X4_obs == 1, X4, NA)
```

The key line is `Y <- 2 + X1 + X2 + X3 + 2*X4 + 2*X5 + rnorm(n, mean = 0, sd = 3)`. This takes a linear combination of your features and then adds some noise.

This is the line that establishes the true relationship:

$$
Y = \beta_0 + \beta_1X_1 + \beta_2X_2+\beta_3X_3+\beta_4X_4+\beta_5X_5 + \epsilon\\= 2 + 1(X_1) + 1(X_2) + 1(X_3) + 2(X_4) + 2(X_5) + \epsilon
$$

Therefore, your $\beta = (2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2)^T$. Use those values to calculate $\mathbb E\big[\hat\beta_i - \beta_i\big]$.